# SKPhysicsContactDelegate methods called with PhysicsKit types?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

I added some convenience methods to `SKPhysicsBody` to more easily cope with them inside the `didBeginContact` method of the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` class.

```
@interface SKPhysicsBody (MyCategory)
-(void)convenience;
@end
```

It appears the delegate uses different types then documented though. When I try to use this convenience method in didBeginContact I get an exception.

When trying the following test code

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    NSLog(@"%@, %d", [contact.bodyA class], [contact.bodyA isKindOfClass:[SKPhysicsBody class]]);
}
```

it will log

```
PKPhysicsBody, 0
```

PKPhysicsBody is part of the (private) PhysicsKit framework.

While the [SKPhysicsContact](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsContact/bodyA) documentation clearly states

```
bodyA
The first body in the contact. (read-only)
@property(readonly, nonatomic) SKPhysicsBody *bodyA
```

Is there a way around this so I can still use a SKPhysicsBody class categories? Or am I misinterpreting something and is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Well PhysicsBody probably utilizes Class Cluster methodology, extensively used in Apple frameworks.
You should use built in contact masks to identify your physics bodies.
Like explained in docs:

categoryBitMask
A mask that defines which categories this physics body belongs to.

Comment: I think there's some confusion, by "categories" I mean an "Objective-C category", not the category of the physics body. I.e. I want to use methods from something like `@interface SKPhysicsBody (myextension)`

Comment: @Pieter Yeah I understand that you want to differentiate types of your physics bodies and check them via introspection, but I suggest you use designated way to do this - categoryBitMask. The way you want to do this is not going to work. Check this why - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassCluster.html

Comment: No, I think you're still confused, I do not want to differentiate anything via introspection. I don't think this is a class cluster issue. If there was an abstract superclass `SKPhysicsBody` which would be passed, all would be fine. The problem is the class passed is not recognised at runtime as a SKPhysicsBody class. If I simply add `@interface SKPhysicsBody (extra)` with one method `-(void)doSomething { NSLog(@"Boo!"); }`, calling this method on a body inside SKPhysicsContact will crash with an exception.

Comment: @Pieter this is exactly what class cluster is about. For example NSArray or NSDictionary and same with SKPhysicsBody do NOT guarantee their class at any point. So you can't just add new methods to them and expect this to work. They have different inner classes at different time for various reasons and this is ok. The documentation is probably wrong not mentioning that.

Comment: Of course having different inner classes is ok, my issue is that the type passed is not of the "abstract superclass" type, as in a class cluster it should. This is not about having a different internal private class handling things, it's about the type not being of the abstract public class, per the documentation `A class cluster is an architecture that groups a number of private, concrete subclasses under a public, abstract superclass.` But maybe I'm completely misunderstanding how this all works.